# How to depend one array values on another array value

Tags: php, arrays

I have two array,
i.e.

```
Array ( 
[0] => Sony Xperia Modern Silver 
[1] => Sony Xperia C Purple 
[2] => Sony Xperia C3 Starry Black 
[3] => Sony Xperia C3 Snow White 
[4] => Sony Xperia C3 Fresh Mint 
[5] => Sony Xperia C4 Dual Mint 
[6] => Sony Xperia C4 Dual White 
[7] => Sony Xperia C4 Dual Black);

And

Array ( 
[0] => 40 
[1] => 40 
[2] => 60 
[3] => 40 
[4] => 40 
[5] => 80 
[6] => 80 
[7] => 100);
```

So In this case first array for NAME's and second array for reviews in %,
how my first array value is depends on second array condition,because we require data(i.e. name of products) when we give condition like if(review >= 60).
In this, My required output is that related name are fetch whose review is greater than or equal to 60 and record is in descending order (record is in descending order depends on that perticuler's reviews )

Comment: Post your attempts. Post your expected output as it looks Unclear

Comment: Please elaborate it more.

Comment: From where are you pulling this info? From a sql database?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?
$ProductName[]=Array ( 
[0] => Sony Xperia Modern Silver 
[1] => Sony Xperia C Purple 
[2] => Sony Xperia C3 Starry Black 
[3] => Sony Xperia C3 Snow White 
[4] => Sony Xperia C3 Fresh Mint 
[5] => Sony Xperia C4 Dual Mint 
[6] => Sony Xperia C4 Dual White 
[7] => Sony Xperia C4 Dual Black);

And

$Reviews[]=Array ( 
[0] => 40 
[1] => 40 
[2] => 60 
[3] => 40 
[4] => 40 
[5] => 80 
[6] => 80 
[7] => 100);

$j=sizeof($ProductName);

for($i=$j;$i>0;$i--) //For descending order
{
    if($Reviews[$i]>=60)
    {
        echo $ProductName[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Ermm there are at least 1 million syntax errors in this answer :o

Comment: Yeah Mr Hanky. It May Be.. Because, Array Declaration Is done by the OP. What Syntax Error is there in For Loop which i added. I didn't touched the array declaration part. Just Given the name to it.

Comment: Thanks for your reply,

Comment: Yeah, i misunderstood the question or question was not properly described/elaborated as Uchhia & Raveenanigam Asked you to do so. I will try to fetch your product name in descending order. Wait for few minute Mr @Gopal.

Comment: Actually we require Names of product is in descending order but the descending order is fully depends on reviews of products. The below example is different than the above one: E.G. [100]="Sony xperia c3 dual sim", [100]="Sony xperia c3 dual sim 1GB RAM Black", [90]="Sony xperia c3 white", [80]="Sony xperia c3 Black",........,[60]....,[50].....,[50].....,[40].......etc.     Like this means our descending order fully depends on reviews of that perticular product.

Comment: Hey @Gopal. I'm Sorry. I can't help. Let people give answer. I don't know answer.